# What method called first than application:did(will)FinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, xcode

I need to perform some what actions before `Main.storyboard` is be loaded
and the controller will call method `viewDidLoad`. Now it turns out that method `viewDidLoad` in controller called before then `application:did(will)FinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate`. How can I guaranteed call a my method in AppDelegate before begin preloaded `Main.storiboard`?

## upd

i have two breakpoints

1. application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate
2. viewDidLoad in ViewController

my debugger first catch breakpoint#2 (in ViewController)
[image: breakpoint#2 tree]
and only second catch breakpoint#1 (in AppDelegate)
[image]
which can lead to such behavior?
`Main.storyboard` Loading standard (info.plist)

Comment: Well, just try to print the names of the functions and run without debugger and tell the result

Answer (score -1):

```
application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)
```

is always called first and then

```
viewDidLoad
```

is called.

In order to check use

```
print(__FUNCTION__)
```

in your **FinishLaunchingWithOptions** and **viewDidLoad** methods

It will just print the name of the method which is called.

If **initWithCoder** is used then flow is as follows

```
init(coder:)
application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)
viewDidLoad()
```

In order to check the order you can see this link for reference
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33804039/app-life-cycle-changes-in-ios-9

Comment: just use `print(__FUNCTION__)` in your function. I hope you are using swift.

Comment: i using obj-c, i can use ``NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__)``, but i see that ``initWithCoder`` in my controller call first than ``application:did(will)FinishLaunchingWithOptions``

Comment: you wrote in your question that viewDidLoad is called before applicationDidFinish.. is that so?

Comment: yes initWithCoder is called first but then applicationDidFinishLaunching is called.

Comment: ok. how i can called my method in ``AddDelegate`` first than ``initWithCoder``? first than did begin loading storyboard?

Comment: initWithCoder is called during nib is Loading

Comment: I know when calling ``initWithCoder``. you say there is no way to perform that before? not sure

Comment: @EvGeniyIlyin it will do like initWithCoder , then applicationFinish and then viewDidLoad. I am unable to find other way for now..